# get class of generic type or generic instance

Tags: java, class, generics, types

I have a method that

- has two type parameters `T` and `S` where `S` is superclass of `T`,
- has an instance `t` of `T` as argument,
- creates a new instance `s` of `S`,
- fills all fields of `s` with the content of `t`.

Here is the code:

```
public static <T extends S, S> S copyAs(T t, Class<S> sClass) {
    S s = sClass.newInstance();
    for (Field f : getAllFields(sClass)) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(s, f.get(t));
    }
    return s;
}

private static Collection<Field> getAllFields(Class<?> cls) {
    Collection<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    while (cls != Object.class)
    {
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(cls.getDeclaredFields()));
        cls = cls.getSuperclass();
    }
    return fields;
}
```

This works perfectly.

For convenience - in case I want to copy as the same class - **I want a second method with just one argument. That method should internally just call `copyAs(myInstance, MyClass.class)` if `myInstance` is of type `MyClass`.**

**How do I do this? Is this possible at all?**

I have tried two ways which both do not work:

```
public static <T> T copy(T t) {
    return copyAs(t, T.class);
    // error: .class cannot be used on type parameter
}
```

and

```
public static <T> copy(T t) {
    return copyAs(t, t.getClass());
    // error: t.getClass() gives Class<? extends Object>, not Class<T>
}
```

Comment: Use case:

I have a bunch of generated classes from xml (using xjc on an xml schema file). They have an inheritance hierarchy. Sometimes I need to (1.) retrieve some object of type `T` from an xml, (2.) deserialize/marshal this object into another xml, but not as `T` but as `S` (effectively just throwing away some of the data).

Comment: `return copyAs(t, t.getClass());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T.class will never work -> you need to do some more reading about how java generics work.

This will do what you want:

```
public static <T> T copy(T t) {
    Class<T> tc = (Class<T>) t.getClass();
    return copyAs(t, tc);
}
```

but it does raise a class cast warning -- there isn't really a way to not do that with the code that you want, feel free to suppress it.

Comment: It should be `return copyAs(t, tc)` instead of `return copy(t, tc)` but I could not make this edit as it needs to have at least 6 edited characters.